# logging node with logfmt format

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js, splunk

our team is working on a next.js application with splunk as our logging tool. we want to console the log in logfmt format. examples:

1. https://brandur.org/logfmt
2. https://www.cloudbees.com/blog/logfmt-a-log-format-thats-easy-to-read-and-write

however, the only library there seems to be for node for logfmt is this [node-logfmt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/logfmt) which was last updated 3 years ago, and probably is a bit outdated. also, as far as i understand, this library only parse the message, so i'll still have to wrap it in a logger module to add standard params like time and log level.

is there any other package that can help logging messages in logfmt format?

Comment: Did you find any relevant libaries?

I run a Node Next.js application on AWS and been experimenting with loki support.

Comment: @diegoaguilar there are none. there are some support in other log packages to reformat the text, but that's hardly any close.
best thing to do it to log as json and use some other method of conversion (in the logger app like Splunk)

Comment: Heard about loki?